# dynamic css at class level

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a JSP code like below.

```
<table id="mytable" cellspacing="0">
<tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
////...
/...//
<tr data-depth="<%=dataDepth%>" class="collapse level<%=dataDepth%>">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and below is the css for class level

```
.level1 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.level2 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.level3 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 45px;
}
.level4 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 60px;
}
.level5 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 75px;
}
```

The above code for class is harcoded for level1,level2,level3,level4,level5. But from JSP code the class level is dynamic and can keep increasing based on <%=dataDepth%> and this has no limit. Can the css also change dynamically with respect to JSP code? Any examples or suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I have idea for using that. I hope this help to you.

You can use `--var`s of css on inline style and using `calc` to dynamic it. see snippet.

```css
.level[data-depth] td:first-child{
  padding-left: calc(var(--depth) * 15px);
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable" cellspacing="0">
  <tr data-depth="0" style="--depth:0;" class="collapse level">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-depth="1" style="--depth:1;" class="collapse level">
    <td>b</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-depth="2" style="--depth:2;" class="collapse level">
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-depth="<%=dataDepth%>" style="--depth:<%=dataDepth%>;" class="collapse level<%=dataDepth%>">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried the same but it didnt work. No errors on inspect. Adeed style as above in addition added calc(var(--depth) * 15px in CSS. Can you send me a JSFiddle example please.